# net use command not working in batch

Tags: batch-file, net-use

I tried to connect to my nas via net use.

```
net use \\192.168.0.xxx\Ben /user:DATASERVER\Ben Password
```

But it didnt do the command, and in cmd it works fine. What I do wrong?

Comment: does the password contains `%` ? Do you use some variables for the command?

Comment: Next characters should be escaped when used in a batch: percentage sign `%`, ampersand `&`, pipe `|`, greater than `>`, less than `<`, caret `^`, exclamation mark `!` (if enabled delayed expansion only). Escaped characters, respectively: `%%`, `^&`, `^|`, `^>`, `^<`, `^^`, `^!` (but `^^!` if enabled delayed expansion)